# JAX-WS + SOAP: How to parse HTTP Client Error

Tags: java, parsing, http, soap, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS + SOAP to communicate to a webservice. I can handle the SOAP message (handleFault) but i cannot understand how to catch HTTP errors, because they occur under the HTTP Java client layer...

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 412: Precondition Failed
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:203)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:177)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:222)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
```

I know the server **should include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation** (and, in fact, i've been told it's doing just that).

My question is: HOW to reach that "entity"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like web service is not implemented according to specification. According to [W3C Note 08 May 2000 on SOAP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383529) (same with SOAP 1.2):

> In case of a SOAP error while processing the request, the SOAP HTTP server MUST issue an HTTP 500 "Internal Server Error" response and include a SOAP message in the response containing a SOAP Fault element (see section 4.4) indicating the SOAP processing error.

Even if there is some "entity" I don't think you should handle that in your application. It would be definitely a hack. If you need to learn what entity is it only once, just use some sniffer tool like Wireshark.

If you really want to ignore HTTP status code you can switch to CXF as a JAX-WS implementation. There you can disable checking HTTP code:

```
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(hw);
client.getRequestContext().put("org.apache.cxf.http.no_io_exceptions", "true");
```

Comment: Let's see... HTTP 500 still is an HTTP error! How can i reach the returned XML? Is there a limitation in the java implementation? I've been told that the SecureBlackbox lib has an object with a property called ServerStatusCode, that contains a post response XML object called responseFromServer, that can be parsed to obtain the error situation.

Comment: @marcolopes Server should return HTTP 500 together with SOAP Fault as XML content, like one shown [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/soap/fault.html). If this fault is specified in WSDL then it will be converted to appropriate Java exception. Regarding SecureBlackbox - do you mean something like [this device](ftp://ftp.blackbox.com/manuals/i/ICOMP_technical_reference.pdf). It looks like the service provided by this device is not SOAP one. It looks like Rest/XML. Also I was not able to find any reference to SecureBlackbox supporting SOAP over HTTP.

Comment: So, even if the correct HTTP error 500 is returned, the service still needs to include the possible errors in the WSDL specification, otherwise java (and other languages??) will never throw an useful exception?

Comment: Turns out that in CXF you can disable checking HTTP code. Maybe it allows you to receive payload (see my edited answer). But in general HTTP codes 200 and 500 are only correct ones for SOAP over HTTP. And yes, possible errors (soap faults) should be specified in WSDL.